# UI routing how to invoke same child from defferent ui-sref

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi friends I am new to Angular and ui routing. I am in stuck with routing.
The following codes i have done and works fine.

home.html

---

```
<div ui-view="menubar"></div>
<div class="content-container content-blocks">
    <div ui-view="homeContent"></div>
</div>
```

header.html

---

```
<div >
    <span class="home-heading">   Hello! Header</span>
</div>
```

homeContent.html

---

```
        <a ui-sref=".postatus">             Open PO Status                  </a>

        <a ui-sref=".accruview" >           Accru View                      </a>
```

appConfig.js

---

```
.state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'home.html',        
        },
        'menubar@home': {
          templateUrl: 'header.html'
        },
        'homeContent@home': {
          templateUrl: 'app/component/home/homeContent.html',
        }
      }
    })
    .state('home.postatus', {
      url: '/postatus',
      views: {
        'menubar@home': {
          templateUrl: 'app/component/navigation-bar/navigationBar.html'
        },
        'homeContent@home': {
          templateUrl: 'app/component/po-status/poStatus.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('home.accruview', {
      url: '/accruview',
      views: {
        'menubar@home': {
          templateUrl: 'app/component/navigation-bar/navigationBar.html'
        },
        'homeContent@home': {
          templateUrl: 'app/component/accru-view/accruView.html'
        }         
      }
    })
```

poStatus.html
    _________________________

```
<span> Hi iam from POStatus</span>


accruView.html
______________________________
<span> Hi iam from Accru View</span>


navigationBar.html
______________________________
<nav class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href ui-sref="postatus">Open PO Status</a></li>
        <li> <a href ui-sref="accruview">Accru View</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Friends I have to add functionality for navigationbar.html.
When I click menu in navigationbar.html it should change the content only in 'homeContent@home' view.
For example, when I click on 'Open PO Status' link from homeContent.html, it should change 
'menubar@home' and 'homeContent@home' views.
but when I am clicking on 'Open PO Status' link from navigationbar.html,it should change 
only 'homeContent@home' view. I dont know how can I move forward.
I am in stuck, can anybody help me out.

Comment: <a ui-sref="home.postatus"> the sref refers to the state name

Comment: Nice , rrd this works fine. But can you ensure that 'menubar@home' view will not get invoked again when I put <a ui-sref="home.postatus"> in my navigationbar.html .

Comment: Well your home.postatus state has views in it - one of which is menubar@home, so it will get invoked, no doubt.